# DOM APIs overloading/proxying in PhantomJS 2.0

Tags: javascript, cookies, phantomjs, hook

I'm trying to create a simple example of DOM APIs overloading/proxying in PhantomJS. My intention to detect if a page tries to read/write the cookies in its scope. To do this I wrote the following PhantomJS 2.0 script:

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onInitialized = function() {
  page.evaluate(function() {
    (function() {
      console.log('onInitialized');
      var cookie_setter = document.__lookupSetter__('cookie');
      var cookie_getter = document.__lookupGetter__('cookie');

      Object.defineProperty(Object.getPrototypeOf(document), 'cookie', {
        get: function() {
          console.log('get cookie');
          return cookie_getter.call(this);
        },
        set: function(value) {
          console.log('set cookie');
          return cookie_setter.apply(this, arguments);
        }
      });
    })();
  });
};

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
  page.evaluate(function() {
    (function() {
      console.log('onLoadStarted');
      var cookie_setter = document.__lookupSetter__('cookie');
      var cookie_getter = document.__lookupGetter__('cookie');

      Object.defineProperty(Object.getPrototypeOf(document), 'cookie', {
        get: function() {
          console.log('get cookie');
          return cookie_getter.call(this);
        },
        set: function(value) {
          console.log('set cookie');
          return cookie_setter.apply(this, arguments);
        }
      });
    })();
  });
};

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
  var log = JSON.parse(msg);
  if (log.type === 'cookie') {
    console.log('cookie');
  }
};

page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
  console.log('page.onLoadFinished: ' + status);
  if (status === 'success') {
    console.log(page.content);
    //phantom.exit();
  }
};

page.open('http://127.0.0.1/phantom/1.html', function(status) {
  /* 
  <html>
  <body>
  <script>var a = document.cookie;</script>
  </body>
  </html>
  */
  page.evaluate(function() {
    (function() {
      console.log('page.open');
      var cookie_setter = document.__lookupSetter__('cookie');
      var cookie_getter = document.__lookupGetter__('cookie');

      Object.defineProperty(Object.getPrototypeOf(document), 'cookie', {
        get: function() {
          console.log('get cookie');
          return cookie_getter.call(this);
        },
        set: function(value) {
          console.log('set cookie');
          return cookie_setter.apply(this, arguments);
        }
      });
    })();
  });
});
```

But I get the following error:

```js
SecurityError: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the     user agent.

  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():4 in __lookupSetter__
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():4
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():17
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():18
SecurityError: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the     user agent.

  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():4 in __lookupSetter__
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():4
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():17
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():18
page.onLoadFinished: success
<html><head></head><body>
<script>var a = document.cookie;</script>
</body></html>
TypeError: Attempting to change the setter of an unconfigurable property.

  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():7 in defineProperty
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():7
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():17
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():18
```

However the same snippet works flawlessly on Firefox/Chrome Dev tools as well as in JSFiddle. Here is the proof: https://jsfiddle.net/vmc6tz9q/3/

This doesn't even work with `--web-security=false` switch as well. Can someone please help me debug this?